# How exactly does SAX parse a document?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm trying to parse some of my first XML documents in SAX by simply implementing `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`, and I don't know if I'm understanding the flow. For a given XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <item>
        <name>One</name>
        <description>The number 1, expressed in letters.
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Two</name>
        <description>The number 2, expressed in letters.
    </item>
</list>
```

What would be the expected order of events in the parser? Am I right in assuming the following:

```
startDocument()
    startElement() -> "list"

        startElement() -> "item"
            startElement() -> "name"
                characters() (>=1 times) -> "One"
            endElement() -> "name"
            startElement() -> "description"
                characters() (>=1 times) -> "The number 1, expressed in letters."
            endElement() -> "description"
        endElement() -> "item"

        startElement() -> "item"
            startElement() -> "name"
                characters() (>=1 times) -> "Two"
            endElement() -> "name"
            startElement() -> "description"
                characters() (>=1 times) -> "The number 2, expressed in letters."
            endElement() -> "description"
        endElement() -> "item"

    endElement() -> "list"
endDocument()
```

Is that pretty much the gist of it?

Also, what's the easiest way to parse? Presently, at each call to `startElement`, I'm saving as a private variable the name of the current element for when I'm parsing data in the `characters` call. Is there an easier/better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've got the gist of it.

SAX is a very low-level interface so don't expect it to be easy. In most SAX applications you will probably want to maintain a stack, where startElement pushes the element name onto the stack, and endElement pops it off. If you're not handling mixed content, then characters() should probably append to a StringBuffer associated with the element on the top of the stack, and you should process the character content in the StringBuffer when the endElement event occurs. That's because character content can be split into multiple calls on characters() any way the parser wants.

Answer (score 1):

The SAX state machine is, unfortunately, not well documented.  Rather than tell you some details, I'd suggest that you write as your first content-handler one that just logs everything that happens to the console, and play with different input.

But... yes, you've got the gist of it.

As far as the "easiest way to parse", I'm tempted to say "not SAX".  In using SAX, one way or another you need to implement a state machine that reflects the structural transitions in the document.  If the doc is simple, you may not even recognize it as a state machine per se.  But if you think about it that way, I think it will be pretty easy to see how to store away what you need as events go by.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure I _have_ to use SAX, as I'm on Android using Restlet, unless you know of a better solution.